# Three fingers gesture ubuntu gnome 15.04

Tags: 15.04, mouse, touchpad, multi-touch, gestures

I have seen this question asked like a billion times but not answer successfull with me so far. I installed ubuntu gnome edition 15.04 but can't seem to have three fingers gestures to work.

I would like to be able to minimize maximize, switch workspace etc...

My touchpad is a elantech (Asus UX32A), I tried touchegg but not working.

Please tell me how to do that with recent version as it seems to have been changed recently...

Thanks !
Victor

Comment: Well, I have Asus with Elantech, and the only this I can do is three finger tap - aka middle mouse button. Also I'm not saying it's impossible to make it all work...

Comment: http://blog.mpiannucci.com/view/multitouchgesture

I finaly found the way ! it is well worth it !

Answer (score 0):

After searching hours I came across that : http://blog.mpiannucci.com/view/multitouchgesture

It worked for me (ubuntu gnome 15.04, asus UX32A)

Thanks !